# How to track down problematic MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I use MySQL (Percona ExtraDB 5.1 to be exact) as my database of choice. Overall, very impressed with performance. The applications that use it are quite large.

We believe that a query is sometimes causing a backup of threads on the database for whatever reason (i.e., memory/buffers). The server has been tweaked countless times to prevent this so it's literally a 1% problem now, but still very annoying. Unless you are monitoring the database server 24/7 you are unlikely to ever see the cause of the backup.

Is there any recommendation (apart from going through the slow query log) which anyone can suggest to track the problematic queries (i.e., reporting via the application)?

Comment: How did you tweak your server? I had performance issues with a web app in the recent past and MySQL Performance Tuning Primer Script (http://www.day32.com/MySQL/) helped a great deal in pin pointing where the bottlenecks lay. That with logging (what you're doing now) and optimizing slow queries solved it for me at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percona Server with XtraDB actually logs both the timestamp and the execution time in microsecond resolution, so you can find the start and the end of the queries precisely.  However, log analysis is probably the wrong approach.  You probably need to use Aspersa's stalk+collect tools.

Answer (score 0):

As you point out in your question, your best bet will be the slow query log:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html

You might also want to log this at the app level:

At the beginning of your scripts, keep a note of what you're about to do and when it started. At the end of it, log this information if the time spent processing the request is higher than a certain threshold.

That way, you'll be able to identify problematic sequences of queries rather than individual queries. (Which, incidentally, might reveal that no individual query is slow but some requests might fire gazillions of small queries.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. This was something i was considering. Slow query log would be great if it actual gave you the ability to log start and end time of query execution that way you can get a better idea of timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this script](http://www.retards.org/projects/mysql/) which allows you to extract a more abstracted representations of the queries causing the problems.

I usually sort the list by the product of frequency and runtime to get the queries causing the most problems.

NB recording the actual start and end of the queries is irrelevant to measuring the queries actually causing locks - from the manual "The time to acquire the initial table locks is not counted as execution time"

You just need to fix the slow stuff.